# Flash message not showing on modal close

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I have a modal where users can put in email addresses to invite people and upon clicking the button, it makes an ajax request to send emails. After the emails are sent, it should flash a success message however it doesn't even though the response says it was successful.

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/send_invite_email',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"emails": $(".email-input").val()},
  success: function() {
    $('#invite-modal').modal('hide');
  }
});
```

InvitesController:

```
def send_invite_email
   @emails = params[:emails]
   @invited_by = current_user.id
   for email in @emails.split(/[\s,]+/)
     InvitationMailer.invite(email, @invited_by).deliver_later
     next if Invitation.find_by_invited_by_and_invitee(@invited_by, email)
     Invitation.create! invited_by: @invited_by, invitee: email
   end
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { 
        flash[:success] = 'Invitation email sent!'
        redirect_to about_path
     }
     format.js
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the response. First you need to add an argument to the success handler to be able to access the data and then within the handler do something with the data

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/send_invite_email',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"emails": $(".email-input").val()},
  success: function(serverResponse) {
    // do something with response
    alert( serverResponse);

    $('#invite-modal').modal('hide');
  }
});
```

Reference [$.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: It's still not showing me any success messages after modal closes. It also doesn't redirect. Basically, these two lines `flash[:success] = 'Invitation email sent!' redirect_to about_path`  don't work. Even though on terminal, it says it was redirected.

Comment: you can't make the page redirect from server in an ajax call, if that's what you want to do why are you using ajax? Alternative is use javascript to redirect

Comment: no ajax call isn't redirecting. The rails controller method is supposed to but it's not.

Comment: please explain expected behavior. A redirect at server will not cause a page redirect within an ajax request, it will only redirect the actual request and page won;t change

Comment: can you tell me how you would redirect with javascript?

Comment: that is a very simple google search  , use `window.location=url`. You might just as well submit your form if you are redirecting and skip the ajax

Answer (score 1):

**Sessions**

As an addition to `charlietfl`'s answer, `sessions` will not be passed through Javascript, so in your current implementation, the "flash" won't be passed at all.

> **The flash is a special part of the session** which is cleared with each request. This means that values stored there will only be available in the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

Since sessions ([of which `flash` is a part](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)) are shared between the client and server (IE server sets the user's session vars), you cannot "pass" session variables through a pure ajax request.

Instead, you either have to pass the data manually, or use the server-side JS (which appears to be what you're doing anyway):

```
#app/controllers/invites_controller.rb
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
   def send_invite_email
      flash[:success] = 'Invitation email sent!'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js #-> app/views/invites/send_invite_email.js.erb
        format.html {  redirect_to about_path }
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
app/views/invites/send_invite_email.js.erb
$("element").html("<%j flash[:success] %>");
```

---

**Ajax**

In your current setup, you're using standard `ajax`.

Ajax stands for [**Asynchronous Javascript And XML**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) - meaning that it's meant to send *asynchronous* requests to your server (IE requests out of scope of standard page loads):

[image]

This means that each request you send to your server will be met with a *response*, which you'll have to handle. You're currently not doing this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/send_invite_email',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"emails": $(".email-input").val()},
  success: function(data) {
    // "data" is the response which you'll be able to use in your DOM
  }
});
```

Because Ajax is asynchronous, it cannot use the `flash` or any other server-side code (as this needs to be loaded into the front-end in order to work).

Simply, you're not going to get any page redirects or flash from your server through ajax. If you want standard functionality (IE for your app to "redirect" etc based on the controller code), don't use ajax.

If you want to send the ajax requests *and* have the likes of redirects etc - you'll be best using the server-side JS that comes with `respond_to`. I wrote code for that above.