# Modal missing login message

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, modal-dialog

Need some help. I've created a login for my site and its all running ok, doing what it should be, except displaying the login successful or unsuccessful on the login modal when logging in. For now, I redirected the page when logged in to specific pages but I don't want that I  want it to just display one of the two messages within the modal. any help or advice would be appreciated. I also appreciate my code may be scrappy but I'm very much a noob at this and still learning

This is my Code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
          }
      }
function loginform() {
        var Username = document.forms["logform"]["uname"].value;
        var Password = document.forms["logform"]["psw"].value;
        params = 'Username=' + Username + '&Password=' + Password;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", '/login', true); // true is asynchronous
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.onload = function () {
          if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("submit-error").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
             var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", '/home', true); // true is asynchronous
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.onload = function ()
          } else {
            console.error(xhttp.statusText);
          }
        };
        xhttp.send(params);
        return false;
      }
```

```css
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = ()
    Username = request.form.get('uname', default="Error")
    Password = request.form.get('psw', default="Error")
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT Username, Password FROM RegistrationFormAccountData WHERE Username=? AND Password=?", (Username, Password) )
        data = cur.fetchall()
    except Exception as err:
        conn.rollback()
    finally:
        conn.close()

        if len(data) == 0:
            return redirect(url_for('reg'))

        query_username = data[0][0]
        query_password = data[0][1]

        print(query_password)
        print(query_username)

        if query_username== Username and query_password == Password:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nav-item" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"> <span> LOGIN </span> </a>
      <div id="id01" class="modal">

        <form name="logform" class="modal-content animate" action="/login" method="POST" onsubmit="return loginform()">
          <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="static/minikarm.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" width="80px" height="80px">
          </div>

          <div class="container">
            <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
            CloseWindow
            <button class="LogBTN" type="submit">Login</button>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
          </div>
          <br>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash message not showing on modal close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292745/flash-message-not-showing-on-modal-close)

Comment: Doesn't look duplicated